# Coldfusion 10 sessionTimeout is not working

Tags: coldfusion, session-timeout, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

I've created the following Application.cfc and everything is working except for one thing. I'm trying to get the Application.cfc to logout after a short period of inactivity. However, none of my efforts with `ApplicationTimeout` or `SessionTimeout` have worked.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thank You

```
<cfcomponent> 
<cfset This.name = "AndWhat"> 
<cfset This.sessionManagement="True"> 
<cfset This.loginstorage="session"> 
<cfset This.datasource = "database">
<cfset This.ormenabled = "true">
<cfset This.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan( 0, 0, 1, 0 )>
<cfset This.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan( 0, 0, 1, 0)>


<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="remote" > 
    <cfif IsDefined("Form.logout")> 
        <cflogout> 
    </cfif> 
    <cflogin >
        <cfif NOT IsDefined("cflogin")> 
            <cfinclude template="loguser.cfm"> 
            <cfabort> 
        <cfelse> 
            <cfif cflogin.name IS "" OR cflogin.password IS ""> 
                <cfoutput> 
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Um, Really?! Please supply a valid username and password!");
                    </script>
                </cfoutput> 
                <cfinclude template="loguser.cfm"> 
                <cfabort> 
            <cfelse > 
                 <cfquery name="myNewLoginQuery" dataSource="database"> 
                    SELECT username, password, policy
                    FROM people 
                    WHERE 
                    username = '#cflogin.name#' 
                    AND password = '#cflogin.password#' 
                </cfquery> 
                <cfif loginQuery.policy NEQ ""> 
                    <cfloginuser name="#cflogin.name#" Password = "#cflogin.password#"> 
                <cfelse> 
                    <cfoutput> 
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("Um, Really?! Please supply a valid username and password!");
                        </script>
                    </cfoutput>     
                    <cfinclude template="loguser.cfm"> 
                    <cfabort> 
                </cfif> 
            </cfif>     
        </cfif> 

    </cflogin>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Dunno, but shouldn't session-centric stuff be managed on `onSessionStart()`, not `onRequestStart()`? I'd also probably not bother with `<cflogin>` if you can avoid it. It really doesn't bring much to the table.

Comment: Just a random guess: try to set different time spans for application timeout and session timeout. App would usually be few hours, session is like 30 min or so. Currently they are the same in your code, it could be a source of the problems.

Comment: Additionally, how do you know that timeouts do not work? I suggest to implement the `onSessionEnd()` handler and use `cflog` to record the timeouts. You'll have more info for the research.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute **idletimeout** to **cflogin** tag. Set the value of idletimeout equal to the value of sessionTimeout. 
You can check the documentation of **cflogin** here: http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_07.html

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into a similar issue. But you should never ever ever run a cfquery with user supplied data without a cfqueryparam tag. you are asking for SQL injection without it.

Answer (score -1):

Need to use CreateTimeSpan  variable for generating time stamp for sessionTimeout  variable.